# Unknown problem with reference

Tags: biblatex, errors

My title is not informative as I do not really know what is the problem. 
I started to get an error as

> ```
> [4] (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/ueuf.fd) [5]
> ! Missing $ inserted.
> <inserted text>
>                 $
> l.505
> ```

where line 505 is `\printbibliography`. I am using

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

any ideas on what can I add here to help identify? Maybe `.bib`? I tried but couldn't find what is the exact cause of it.

**`.tex` document**

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
%\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{mathtools} %%used for \usetagform{roman}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,%
  linkcolor=teal,%
  urlcolor=teal%
}%

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for proof environment.
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Notes.bib}

\usepackage{showlabels}%For writing purposes. Comment at the end.

\usepackage[left=1.2in,right=1.2in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\weak}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\ind}[1]{{\bf 1}_{\left\{ {#1} \right\}} }
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
%% \newcommand{\an}{\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}}

%% \DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\esssup}{ess\,sup}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\supp}{supp}


\newtagform{roman}[\renewcommand{\theequation}{\roman{equation}}]()

\title{Report on \cite{BMN2009}}
\date{\today}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} %%included in init
\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem} 
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma} %%included in init
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition} 
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition} %%included in init
\newtheorem{note}{Note} %%included in init 
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm} %%included in init

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**`.bib` document**

```
@article{BMN2009,
 ISSN = {00029947, 10886850},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/40302925},
 author = {Boris Baeumer and Mark M. Meerschaert and Erkan Nane},
 journal = {Transactions of the American Mathematical Society},
 number = {7},
 pages = {3915--3930},
 publisher = {American Mathematical Society},
 title = {Brownian Subordinators and Fractional Cauchy Problems},
 volume = {361},
 year = {2009}
}

@article{Z1994,
author = {Zaslavsky, G.M.},
year = {1994},
month = {09},
pages = {110-122},
title = {Fractional kinetic equation for Hamiltonian chaos},
volume = {76},
journal = {Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena},
doi = {doi:10.1016/0167-2789(94)90254-2}
}

@article{BM2001,
author = {Baeumer, Boris and Meerschaert, Mark},
year = {2001},
month = {03},
pages = {481-500},
title = {Stochastic solutions for fractional Cauchy problems},
volume = {4},
journal = {Fractional_Calculus and Applied Analysis}
}

@misc{K2011,
author = {Davar Khoshnevisan},
title = {Topics in Probability, Levy Processes, Lecture Notes},
howpublished = {Available at \url{https://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/math7880/S11/Chapters/Ch8.pdf}(2020/05/05)}
}

@article{AZ2001,
author = {Allouba, Hassan and Zheng, Weian},
year = {2001},
month = {05},
title = {Brownian-Time Processes: The PDE Connection and the Half-Derivative Generator},
volume = {29},
journal = {Annals of Probability},
doi = {10.1214/aop/1015345772}
}

@article{SKM1990,
author = {Srivastava, Niraj and Kaufman, Charles and Muller, Gerhard},
year = {1990},
month = {01},
pages = {549},
title = {Hamiltonian Chaos},
volume = {4},
journal = {Computers in Physics},
doi = {10.1063/1.4822945}
}

@article{MS2004,
author = {Meerschaert, Mark and Scheffler, Hans-Peter},
year = {2004},
month = {09},
pages = {623-638},
title = {Limit theorems for continuous-time random walks with infinite mean waiting times},
volume = {41},
journal = {Journal of Applied Probability},
doi = {10.1017/S002190020002043X}
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole code to be able to help you.

Comment: Let me simplify it with a minimal version that creates the problem and will add.

Comment: @antshar I included all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the problem if you continue the compilation and then look at the output. The problematic entry is this one:

[image]

And the problem is the underscore in the journal of this entry:

```
journal = {Fractional_Calculus and Applied Analysis}
```

Comment: Ah thanks a lot. It seems to me weird that it only raises an error when I add the very last entry "@book{...}".

Comment: @Jo' The entry `BM2001` will throw an error about `! Missing $ inserted.` if it is cited (or otherwise added to the bibliography) in your document. That error will always appear due to unescaped `_` and does not depend on any other entries being present or not.